# Faster infinite loop

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, while-loop

I wrote this java loop to simulate data source on some benchmark test. Use TimerTask to calculate delta count value per second. This can perform about 500,000,000 on my laptop without any work in the loop:

```
int count = 0;
while (true) {
    count++;
}
```

But I occasionally noticed that loop like this can even reach 40,000,000,000 !

```
final int LOOP = 1000000;
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I have tested that any LOOP value bigger than 1 can have significant performance improvement, or write more lines of "count++;" inside while-loop instead of for-loop. I'm totally confused, have any ideas?

I have viewed the bytecode of the two and found the later loop even do more instructions, and I have use "-XX:+PrintCompilation" and found no big difference. Is there any thing except JIT compiler will do some fancy performance optimization tricks?

I use this tool to measuring speed:

```
public class ThroughputPeriodProbe extends TimerTask implements ThroughputProbe {

private static final long PERIOD = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

private static Timer timer = new Timer("THROUHPUT_PROBE");

@Override
public void through() {
    amount++;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    final long currentAmount = amount;
    long delta = currentAmount - lastAmount;
    final long rate = (long) ((delta / (double) PERIOD) * 1000);
    System.out.println(name + ": " + rate);
    lastAmount = currentAmount;
}

public ThroughputPeriodProbe(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, PERIOD);
}

/** The Last amount. */
private long lastAmount;

/** The Sum. */
private long amount;

/** The Name. */
private final String name;
}
```

Used like this:

```
private ThroughputProbe count = new ThroughputPeriodProbe("Count");

while (true) {
    count.through();
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course.  The JIT is likely to optimize your second nested loop to `count += LOOP`;

Comment: the second code example does 1000000x the work of loop one. please post the code on how you are measuring the code

Comment: Bytecode is nearly irrelevant, the JIT compiler does most optimizations. Such as eliminating that loop. Btw, you can expect to serially-increment (it is important that it is serial) as much in a second as your CPU speed multiplied by a second, so 4 billion when running at 4GHz and so on. Plus some noise, but any significant deviations point toward fundamentally different code being executed.

Comment: But if I replace with count+=1000000 in the first loop, that is actually 1000000x from the performance result.

Comment: Measuring Java speed with "simulations" often gives you wrong results because of the JIT optimizes your simulation to something you don't expect. You should better measure the speed of your productive code.

Comment: The compiler is absolutely justified to do *any* series of writes to `count`, including counting downwards or never writing to `count` at all. The nature of the question is that we can't know what the answer is unless we find out what the compiler has decided to do with the code, and that requires looking at the JIT.